# How to get getStateLocation() in the eclipse plugin that implements BundleActivator?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plugin that extends AbstractUIPlugin

```
package lsclipse;
public class LSclipse extends AbstractUIPlugin {
```

With it, I can get the state location directory using following code.

```
public static final String baseDir = \
     lsclipse.LSclipse.getDefault().getStateLocation().toOSString();
```

And this directory maps into `WORKSPACE/.metdata/.plugin/PROJECT` which is handy 
[image]

However with a plugin that implements BundleActivator

```
package lsclipse;
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
```

I can't get the state location().

[image]

I could use `Platform.getLocation().toFile().toString();` to get the workspace for this plugin, but it is the base directory for the `WORKSPACE`, not `WORKSPACE/.metdata/.plugin/PROJECT`.

How can I get the state location from Activator? My plugin is headless RCP, so I don't want (or can't) inherit from AbstarctUIPlugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.java
public static IPath getStateLocation(Bundle bundle)
```

should give you data area for the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative would be to try `getEnvironmentInfo()` if your Activator class supports it.  Through the EnvironmentInfo instance you get back, you can find any arguments passed in when Eclipse was invoked.  If you're running headless you might be able to pass in as an argument an acceptable directory path for your plugin's state store location.

Answer (score 0):

Simply extend Plugin not AbstractUIPlugin that does not have any ui dependencies but has the same method you mentioned.